# Origin of the names “thionyl” and “sulfuryl”

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

**Compounds in question:**

1. [Thionyl chloride - $\ce{SOCl2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thionyl_chloride)
2. [Sulfuroyl dichloride/Sulfuryl chloride - $\ce{SO2Cl2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuryl_chloride)

I understand that the "thio" prefix is often used when sulphur replaces oxygen in its compounds, like "thioalcohol" or "thiosulphate". I also note that sulphur and sulfur for the same element $\ce{S}$.

However, even after countless attempts, I manage to swap the two compounds with each other, and have not been able to accurately identify their formulae when their names are given (and vice-versa). So, if someone asked me the name of $\ce{SO2Cl2}$, I would respond with thionyl chloride or sulfuryl chloride, and never be sure which one is which.

The names of other inorganic compounds are generally logical and memorable. The use of prefixes like *meta*, *ortho*, *per*, etc. is logical as well. However, these two sulphur compounds are very confusing. This makes me ask the question:

> What is the rule/logic/reason behind the naming of these two inorganic compounds?

I hope if I know the reason I'll be better able to recall their formulae from their names and vice-versa.

Comment: I guess these compounds were named by the wish of the person who discovered or studied them, and then the names were accepted by other chemists. Take for example, aniline, phenol, anisole, benzene, ammonia etc.

Comment: Perhaps you can use IUPAC names, but I don't know if those names are known universally.

Comment: The general convention, as it seems, is that $\ce{thionyl->O=S< , sulfuryl->O2S<, and sulfonyl->O2S<}$. Sulfonyl is used in organic chemistry and sulfuryl in inorganic chemistry.

Comment: @ShoubhikRajMaiti "Take for example, aniline, phenol, anisole, benzene, ammonia etc." at least these names do not clash with each other as the above sulphur compounds' names do.

Comment: @ShoubhikRajMaiti " IUPAC names" Sulfuroyl dichloride is the IUPAC name...

Comment: @ShoubhikRajMaiti " general convention, as it seems" yes, thanks! perhaps you're right on that.

Comment: I don't understand your points.  It might be difficult to memorize them, But they are different compounds with different names under all circumstances

Comment: @Alchimista As I said in my original post, inorganic nomenclature is generally systematic. Yes, different compounds may have different names. But the prefixes themselves follow a certain rule or logic. As an example the "thio" prefix occurs when sulphur replaces oxygen in its compound. But the compounds in the above question are very closely related in their structure and their names are also almost similar. However, their does not seem to be a reason as to why one compound got the "thionyl" prefix, and the other got the "sulfuryl" prefix, besides, what do these prefixes stand for in general?

Comment: @Alchimista Ok, I know the thionyl group has a wikipedia entry and so does sulfuryl (and what groups these prefixes stand for), but that page does not do a good job of explaining why one group is called thionyl and the other is called sulfuryl? Are the two names just randomly assigned to these two groups? _There must have been some structural feature/differences that made one group get the name thionyl, and the other got sulfuryl_. "thio" suggests sulfur, but "sulfuryl" also suggests sulfur. It seemed very hard for me to relate their names to their structure, hence I asked this question.

Comment: This is right what I do not get. Thionyl and sulfuryl are different they must get different names.  Perhaps compare the alternative names sulphinyl and sulphonyl for  the two and you see the rationale behind.

Comment: @Alchimista Yes, they are different compounds and yes they have and should have different names. However, I feel their names should have some sort of underlying rule as to which group got what name. Consider the series of oxoacids pf phosphorus ([list](http://chem-guide.blogspot.in/2010/04/oxides-and-oxyacids-of-phosphorous_02.html)), they too have structures similar to each other, one or two of them even have peroxide linkages. They are all different compounds. Yet, *their names are closely tied to their structure and oxidation states*, unlike the two sulphur groups we are discussing above.

Comment: Thio- , as  azo- when N is involved, etc is replacement nomenclature . It is reserved to compound in which one original atom dictating a name of a compound or of a class of compound is formally replaced. What is curious is that the simpler IUPAC recommended names are never (perhaps rarely) used.  At least in organic chemistry. Just to be clear, this is confusing me as well it confuses you.

Comment: @Alchimista I honestly don't see how your new comment connects/agrees/disagrees with my previous comment? I mean are we both agreed on the fact that the names "sulfuryl" and "thionyl" are rather arbitrary seeming and deserve some systematic analysis?

Comment: Or compare sulforous and sulfuryl than. Obviously you cannot compare name belonging to different systems or asystematically given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Different nomenclatures by IUPAC

For the convenience of the reader, here are the names of the compounds as mentioned in the IUPAC's 2005 Red Book<sup>[1, p 129]</sup>:

- $\ce{SO2Cl2 = [SCl2O2]}$ – *sulfuryl dichloride* or sulfur dichloride dioxide<sup>[a]</sup>, *sulfuryl dichloride*<sup>[b]</sup>, dichloridodioxidosulfur<sup>[c]</sup>;
- $\ce{SOCl2 = [SCl2O]}$ – *thionyl dichloride* or sulfur dichloride oxide<sup>[a]</sup>, *sulfurous dichloride*<sup>[b]</sup>, dichloridooxidosulfur<sup>[c]</sup>

<sup><sub>[a] – acceptable common name, [b] – functional replacement name, [c] – systematic (additive) name</sub></sup>

The names which will be pertinent to this discussion are marked with italics, they should otherwise still be upright.

Also note that $\ce{H2SO4 = [SO2(OH)2]}$ is *sulfuric acid*<sup>[a]</sup>, dihydroxidodioxidosulfur<sup>[c]</sup>. The molecular entity $\ce{H2SO3 = [SO(OH)2]}$ is *sulfurous acid*<sup>[a]</sup>, dihydroxidooxidosulfur<sup>[c]</sup>.

TL; DR: The general scheme of things is acid $\to$ radical, and the suffix used in this purpose is *-yl*. The difference comes from overlap as "properly" both radicals would have the same result: *sulfuryl*.

### Etymology and history

Historically, the terms 'sulfureous' (sulphureous) and 'sulfurous' (sulphurous) date back to the 16th century. Lavosier was first to introduce the adjectives 'sulfuric' and 'sulfurous' to name acids containing sulfur in 1787<sup>[2]</sup>:

> SULPHURIC, SULPHUROUS
>
> The adjectives *sulphureous* and *sulphurous* meaning "pertaining to, or of the nature of, sulphur", date from the 16th century. The well-known oxy-acid was then known as the oil of vitriol (q.v.). In 1787, in the *Méthode de Nomenclature Chimique*, Lavosier Proposed the name **sulphuric acid** (Fr. *sulfurique)* for oil of vitriol and **sulphurous acid** (Fr. *sulfureux*) for the related acid containing proportionately less oxygen.<sup>[2, p 208]</sup>

The suffix *-yl* designates (hypothetically) as having derived from something.<sup>[2]</sup>

> -YL
>
> The suffix *-yl*, adapted from Fr. *-yle*, is derived from Gk. *hylē* which, in addition to meaning "wood", also means "the stuff or raw material (of any kind) from which a thing is made.<sup>[2, p 231]</sup>
>
> [---]
>
> (2) In the name of a radical formed by the removal of a hydroxyl group $\ce{-OH}$ from an acid.<sup>[2, p 232]</sup>
>
> [---]
>
> (b) Inorganic acids. A number of oxygenated inorganic radicals may be regarded as derived from acids (or from hypothetical acids) by the removal of one or more $\ce{-OH}$ groups. Such a radical is normally named by replacing the suffix *-ic* of the name ofthe acid by *-yl*. The more important of these radicals are *sulphuryl* $\ce{SO2\!\!:}$ (cf. sulphuric acid $\ce{SO2(OH)2}$) ... *nitrosyl* $\ce{NO}-$ (cf. nitrous acid $\ce{NO$.$\!OH}$)<sup>[2, p 232]</sup> [---]

As we can see, the *-yl* name does not care about the oxidation state of the acid. For sulfur, we see that both *sulfur**ic*** + ***-yl*** and + *sulfur**ous*** + ***-yl*** would give the same result: *sulfur**yl***. One of them had to be different. For this purpose, the Greek language was used for the radical of sulfurous acid, and a Latin (possibly Sanskrit<sup>[2, p 20]</sup>) form remained for the radical of sulfuric acid.<sup>[2]</sup> This is an historic accident, it could have easily been the other way round.

> THIONYL
>
> The name given by Schiff in 1857 to the radical $\ce{SO\!\!:}$ as in thionyl chloride $\ce{SOCl2}$. It was formed from Gk. *theion*, sulphur, + *-yl* (q.v.). The radical may be regarded as the characteristic group of sulphurous acid $\ce{SO(OH2)2}$; compare *sulphuryl* $\ce{SO2\!\!:}$, the characteristic group of sulfuric acid.
>
> (It is fortunate that the L. and Gk. names for sulphur (*sulfur* and *theion*) are quite different so that two different names could be formed for the two radicals.)<sup>[2, p 214]</sup>
>
> SULPHURYL
>
> The radical $\ce{SO2\!\!:}$, the characteristic group of sulphuric acid $\ce{SO2(OH)2}$ (see *-yl*), e.g. sulphuryl chloride $\ce{SO2Cl2}$ (1867)<sup>[2, p 208]</sup>

For the functional replacement name, $\ce{SOCl2}$ is named sulfurous dichloride to tie the radical more directly to its acid as well, sulfurous acid. Historically, as noted, the approach here was to use different languages of origin for the main element. This was possible because the words were very different.

If you wish to operate with common names, there is always some historic memorisation. Since this is a binary system, you could remember one and automatically derive the other. But as stated, this will not work for other similar cases: *nitrosyl* is for nitrous acid radical, not nitric acid.

---

### References and bibliography

[1] Connelly, N. G.; Damhus, T.; Hartshorn, R. M.; Hutton, A. T. Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry; The Royal Society of Chemistry, 2005. ('[IUPAC Red Book](https://old.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf)')

[2] Flood, W. E. The Origins of Chemical Names, 1st Edition.; Oldbourne, 1963.